# Regex to validate letters numbers and specific special characters

Tags: regex, validation

I have unsuccessfully be looking around the web for such a simple regex and can't seem to put it together.

I need a regex which allows any letter, numbers, whitespace and particular special characters only (@ # $ & ( ) - _ /)

```
"Test #123 @Sample/test"  is valid
"Test ^ £300"             is not valid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you could try the below regex,

```
^[\w\s@#$&()\/-]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/2)

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[\w\s@#$&()\/-]+` Matches one or more characters from the list.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am quite new to regex, I tried this `/[\w\[\]@-_()#$&]*/` but I wasn't too sure of anchors.

Comment: anchors are very important while doing validations.